# MVC ASP.NET search filter by int

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to filter view records via a search for a int? It words but a string but when I try any adapt it to draw all records that match an int I get error: DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types. in reference to the return view.

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder,string search)
      {
        ViewBag.TimeSortParam = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Time_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.PrioritySortParam = sortOrder == "Priority" ? "Priority_desc" : "";
        var incidents = from s in db.Incidents.Include(i => i.Defect).Include(i =>   i.Operator)
                        select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            incidents = incidents.Where(s => s.IncidentID.Equals(search));
        }
 return View(incidents.ToList());
```

View

```
Find by id: @Html.TextBox("Search")
```

I can see the problem is I am using a string for but I cant find a solution for int

Comment: What type is `Incident.IncidentID`?

Comment: it is an INT. I've tried afew thing like solutions like Index(string sortOrder,int search) prehaps something like if (search == null)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested this worked, although I am not sure its the most efficient way to filter by an int:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, int? search)
    {
        ViewBag.TimeSortParam = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Time_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.PrioritySortParam = sortOrder == "Priority" ? "Priority_desc" : "";
        var incidents = from s in db.Incidents.Include(i => i.Defect).Include(i => i.Operator)
                        select s;
        if (search != null)
        {
            incidents = incidents.Where(s => s.IncidentID == (search));
        }}
 return View(incidents.ToList());
```

Comment: Sorta works, I get this error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context. on this line:
return View(await requests.ToListAsync());

Answer (score 0):

In your statement, change to:

`s.IncidentID==Convert.ToInt32(search)`

Comment: got "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." @ return View(incidents.ToList());